# Passing a variable to onload function within a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, for-loop

I have the following simple JavaScript that loads a bunch of images and places them on HTML canvas (canvasCTX is the 2D canvas context):

```
for (var i=0 ;i<10; i++) {   
  var placementX = i*25;
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.src = 'assets/png/' + i + '.png';
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    canvasCtx.drawImage(imageObj,placementX,0);
  };
}
```

Now the problem I find is that all the images are placed at the same place - the last variable created by the loop. I think that's because the for loop continues to run whilst images are being loaded, as the onload is an asynchronous event.

How do I make sure each image gets the correct `placementX` from it's turn in the `for loop`?

Answer (score 1):

try this code .

```
function draw(placementX , imagePath)
{

  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.src=imagePath;        
  console.log(placementX , "before loading");//to ensure that x befor image loading is the same after loading

  image.onload=(function()
  { 
                canvas.drawImage(image , placementX  , 0);
                console.log(placementX , " after loading");//to ensure that x befor image loading is the same after loading

  });
}

var placementX =0;

for (var i=0 ;i<10; i++) 
{   
     placementX = i*25;
     draw('assets/png/' + i + '.png' , placementX );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure.

```
for (var i=0 ;i < 10; i++) {   
    (function(x){
        var placementX = x*25;
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src = 'assets/png/' + x + '.png';
        imageObj.onload = function() {
        canvasCtx.drawImage(imageObj,placementX,0);
        };
    })(i);

}
```

Comment: couldn't get this method to work for some reason although I did find a solution by putting the onload in a separate function and calling that  in the for loop, whilst sending the relevant variable to it at the time. I'm wondering if this method tries to achieve the same thing.

Comment: This suggested method can work, but is less efficient than defining a single function outside the loop and calling it as needed from within.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var i=0
    function update_image()
    { if(i<10)
    {   
          var placementX = i*25;
          var imageObj = new Image();
          imageObj.src = 'assets/png/' + i + '.png';
          imageObj.onload = function() {
            canvasCtx.drawImage(imageObj,placementX,0);
           i++;
    update_image();
          }
        }
update_image();
```